# ViewHolder Layout Updates don't apply from onBindViewHolder()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**The setup** I've got a `RecyclerView` with a custom adapter and custom `ViewHolder`s.

I understand the `onCreateViewHolder()` method is called when the `RecyclerView` is running out of ViewHolders to recycle and needs a new one. So I'm just inflating a layout in there and passing it to a new `ViewHolder.`

Furthermore, `onBindViewHolder()` is responsible for filling the `ViewHolder` with data as soon as a new `ViewHolder` has been created or recycled by the `RecyclerView`. So what I'm doing in there is calling my method `holder.setNode()` to pass a data object to the `ViewHolder`.

**The behavior I'm seeing** When the activity first launches, all entries are correct. When I'm adding new entries or deleting existing ones, however, things start to get a bit funny.

- the `title` `TextView` is always set correctly
- the background color of the main layout changes seemingly at will, I'm assuming because the `RecyclerView` is reusing old ones
- as does the custom view I have implemented, even though I'm invalidating it and passing it new values which change its appearance noticeably

So I'm wondering: Why aren't those values changed in `onBindViewHolder()` as soon as views get reused? Or if I'm wrong, what's the real reason for the random switching of layouts?

---

## TaskListAdapter

```
class TaskListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskListAdapter.TaskViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<NodeHandler.DbNode> dbNodeList = new ArrayList<>();
...

@Override
public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.small_task_view, parent, false);
    return new TaskViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final NodeHandler.DbNode dbNode = dbNodeList.get(position);
    holder.setNode(dbNode);
    holder.wrapper.findViewById(R.id.card_details).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

...

public static class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
    private FrameLayout wrapper;
    private TextView title;
    private NodeHandler.DbNode dbNode;

    public TaskViewHolder(View view) {
        ...
    }

    public void setTitle(String str) {
        title.setText(str);
    }

    public void setMarkers(@IntRange(from = 1, to = Node.MAX_URGENCY) int urgency, @IntRange(from = 1, to = Node.MAX_IMPORTANCE) int importance) {
        if(!dbNode.isAppointment()) {
            wrapper.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(wrapper.getContext(), R.color.lightGray));
        }
        ((QuadrantView) wrapper.findViewById(R.id.quadrant_view)).setDimensions(importance, urgency);
        // setDimensions will invalidate the view
    }

    public void setNode(NodeHandler.DbNode dbNodeObject) {
        this.dbNode = dbNodeObject;
        setTitle(dbNode.toString());
        setMarkers(dbNode.getUrgency(), dbNode.getImportance());
        setTips();
    }
}
}
```

Let me know if anything else could matter here. I'd be happy to update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Values are indeed changed in `onBindViewHolder` as soon as views get reused.

The real reason for the seemingly random switching of layouts is that `onBindViewHolder` is currently implemented in a way that assumes that the `ViewHolder` was freshly created and is being bound for its first time. `onBindViewHolder` should instead be implemented in a way that assumes that the `ViewHolder` being bound is being reused so it should either:

1. reset all the values of the `ViewHolder` to default values first before setting them to other values or
2. make sure that everything is set inside `onBindViewHolder`, so one cannot tell that it was ever previously bound to something else.

**Random background color changes:**

You are right for suspecting that the random background color problem is caused by the `RecyclerView` reusing `ViewHolder`s.

The reason why this is happening is because of the following code:

```
    if(!dbNode.isAppointment()) {
        wrapper.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(wrapper.getContext(), R.color.lightGray));
    }
```

It only sets the background if the `ViewHolder` is not an appointment. So if a `ViewHolder` that is being reused was previously not for an appointment, but is currently for one that is now an appointment, it's background color will be inappropriate.

to fix this, do any of the following:

- set the background color of the `ViewHolder` to some default color before the if statement is executed (as per solution 1 mentioned above):

  ```
  wrapper.setBackgroundColor(/* default background color */);
  if(!dbNode.isAppointment()) {
      wrapper.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(wrapper.getContext(), R.color.lightGray));
  }
  ```
- add an else block to the if statement to set the background color of the `ViewHolder` to the appropriate color (as per solution 2 mentioned above)

  ```
  if(!dbNode.isAppointment()) {
      wrapper.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(wrapper.getContext(), R.color.lightGray));
  }
  else
  {
      wrapper.setBackgroundColor(/* appointment background color */);
  }
  ```
- override the `RecyclerView.Adapter`'s [getItemViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) to return different view types based on `dbNode.isAppointment()`, and create different [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) subclasses for displaying each of them

p.s. I don't know what the problem could be regarding the custom views...sorry

Comment: Hey man, I'm stupefied. Completely overlooked this. I've just made it so that the custom view is replaced with a completely new custom view which works but obviously is hideous. I'm going to ask a different question. Thanks!